# $.each() Adding Tab Spaces To Each Line Using repeat()

Tags: javascript, jquery

### Brief

I'm working on my jQuery Syntax Highlight Script and I want to implement a beautifier which minifies the code then beautifies it by adding new lines and tab spaces where needed.

I'm working on the `CSS` section at the moment and I'm having trouble adding the tab spaces to each line between the `{` and `}`.

### Live Examples:

[**> View On CodePen**](http://codepen.io/MrTIMarshall2512/pen/KaboKP)

**> View Below**

```js
code = $(".input").html().trim();

if (code) {
  code = code
    // REMOVE TAB SPACES
    .replace(/(    )/gi,'')
    // REMOVE NEW LINES
    .replace(/[\n\r]/g,'')
    // REMOVE SPACES BETWEEN SECTIONS
    .replace(/(;|{|})(\s+)([^ \s+])/g,'$1$3')
    .replace(/(;|{|})(\s+)([^ \s+])/g,'$1$3')
    .replace(/(\*\/)(\s+)([^ \s+])/g,'$1$3');
}
$('.minified').text(code);

minified = $('.minified').html();

if (minified) {
  minified = minified
    .replace(/(\;|\}|\{)/gi,'$1\n\r')
    .replace(/((\/\*)(| )([^"'\s\n]+)(| )(\*\/))/gi,'\n\r$1\n\r');
  
  var level = 0;
  var lines = minified.split("\n");
  $.each(lines, function(n, elem) {
    last = elem[elem.length -1]
    if (last === "{") { level = level + 1; }
    else if (last === "}") { level = level - 1; }
    else {
      var tab = "    ".repeat(level);
      elem = tab + elem;
    }
  });
}
$('.beautified').text(minified);
```

```css
.wrap {
  float:left;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 20px;
}
.wrap > h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
pre {
  float: left;
  width:100%;;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <h1>INPUT</H1>
  <pre class="input">
  div.highlight { 
      background:#FFFFFF;
      border:1px solid #E0E0E0;
      font-family:"Courier New",Courier,monospace;
      overflow: hidden;
  }
  div.highlight pre{
      width: 100%;
      overflow: auto;
      padding:0;
      margin:0;
      font-size:13px;
      clear: both;
  }

  /* tabs */
  div.highlight ul.tabs {
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
      margin: 0;
      list-style: none;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
      width: 100%;
  }
  div.highlight ul.tabs li {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0 5px;
      float: left;
      background: none;
      border-bottom: 1px dashed #CCC;
      line-height:1.0em;
      color: #CCC;
      cursor: pointer;
  }
  div.highlight ul.tabs li.active {
      border-bottom: none;
      cursor: default;
  }
  div.element {
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
      flex-flow: column-reverse wrap;
  }
  </pre>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <h1>MINIFIED</H1>
  <pre class="minified"></pre>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <h1>BEAUTIFIED</H1>
  <pre class="beautified"></pre>
</div>
```

### Questions

1. How do I correctly loop through each line and if the line doesn't end with an opening ( `{` ) or closing ( `}` ) curly bracket, indent the code to the with either a tab our four white spaces timed by the `level`?

> **UPDATE 1). A Working Version Via Regex For `CSS` One Indent Only**
>
> This version will only work for one indent and for CSS only, however
>   I'd like to get my other version working to use for other languages
>   and to indent further for `@media` queries, indenting the code further
>   within:
>
> [**> Example on CodePen**](http://codepen.io/MrTIMarshall2512/pen/YNdLrz)
>
> **> Example Below**
>
> ```js
> > 
> >     code = $(".input").html().trim();
> > 
> >     if (code) {
> >       code = code
> >         // REMOVE TAB SPACES
> >         .replace(/(    )/gi,'')
> >         // REMOVE NEW LINES
> >         .replace(/[\n\r]/g,'')
> >         // REMOVE SPACES BETWEEN SECTIONS
> >         .replace(/(;|{|})(\s+)([^ \s+])/g,'$1$3')
> >         .replace(/(;|{|})(\s+)([^ \s+])/g,'$1$3')
> >         .replace(/(\*\/)(\s+)([^ \s+])/g,'$1$3');
> >     }
> >     $('.minified').text(code);
> > 
> >     minified = $('.minified').html();
> > 
> >     if (minified) {
> >       minified = minified
> >         .replace(/(\;|\}|\{)/gi,'$1\n\r')
> >         .replace(/((\/\*)(| )([^"'\s\n]+)(| )(\*\/))/gi,'\n\r$1\n\r')
> >         .replace(/(([a-zA-Z0-9 -]+)(:)([a-zA-Z0-9 -#%"-., ]+)(;))/g,'    $1');
> >     }
> >     $('.beautified').text(minified);
> > 
> >
> ```
>
> ```css
> > 
> >     .wrap {
> >       float:left;
> >       width: 400px;
> >       margin: 20px;
> >     }
> >     .wrap > h1 {
> >       text-align: center;
> >     }
> >     pre {
> >       float: left;
> >       width:100%;;
> >       height: 400px;
> >       border: 1px solid #000000;
> >       overflow: auto;
> >     }
> > 
> >     pre.minified {
> >       height: 50px;
> >     }
> > 
> >
> ```
>
> ```html
> > 
> >     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
> >     <div class="wrap">
> >       <h1>INPUT</H1>
> >       <pre class="input">
> >       div.highlight { 
> >           background:#FFFFFF;
> >           border:1px solid #E0E0E0;
> >           font-family:"Courier New",Courier,monospace;
> >           overflow: hidden;
> >       }
> >       div.highlight pre{
> >           width: 100%;
> >           overflow: auto;
> >           padding:0;
> >           margin:0;
> >           font-size:13px;
> >           clear: both;
> >       }
> > 
> >       /* tabs */
> >       div.highlight ul.tabs {
> >           overflow: hidden;
> >           padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
> >           margin: 0;
> >           list-style: none;
> >           border-bottom: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
> >           width: 100%;
> >       }
> >       div.highlight ul.tabs li {
> >           padding: 0;
> >           margin: 0 5px;
> >           float: left;
> >           background: none;
> >           border-bottom: 1px dashed #CCC;
> >           line-height:1.0em;
> >           color: #CCC;
> >           cursor: pointer;
> >       }
> >       div.highlight ul.tabs li.active {
> >           border-bottom: none;
> >           cursor: default;
> >       }
> >       div.element {
> >           flex-direction: row;
> >           flex-wrap: nowrap;
> >           flex-flow: column-reverse wrap;
> >       }
> >       </pre>
> >     </div>
> >     <div class="wrap">
> >       <h1>MINIFIED</H1>
> >       <pre class="minified"></pre>
> >     </div>
> >     <div class="wrap">
> >       <h1>BEAUTIFIED</H1>
> >       <pre class="beautified"></pre>
> >     </div>
> > 
> >
> ```

Comment: What do you mean by 'tab spaces'?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody `' '`, used to indent code, tab space or four white spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close. In the code you have, `elem` is a local variable inside the function you pass to `each`. You modify it to be indented, but then the program forgets about it when the function returns at the end of the iteration. You'll want to assign it back to `lines`, probably with `lines[n] = elem`. Edit: `$.map` may be more appropriate.

Then, another variant of the same problem occurs. `lines` is updated, but `minified` is still the same. You can use `minified = lines.join('\n')` to glue the pieces back together and update `minified`.

Comment: Thank you @guest your first suggestion works a charm! [Updated Example](http://codepen.io/MrTIMarshall2512/pen/KaboKP), would you still recommend using `$.map` and if so, how would this be done please?

Comment: It's just a matter of taste. [map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) calls a given function for each element, passing the element as an argument. It returns an array with the return values. So you'd do `indentedLines = $.map(lines, function (elem) { ...; return indent + elem; });`

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation algorithm isn't working for various reasons.

1) You need to write in the `lines` array like so: `lines[n] = tab + elem;`
2) You mistakenly assigned `minified` instead of `lines` to `$('.beautified')`
3) Your code was not indenting deeper than 1 level. I modified it to indent at any depth, and added a codepen example to demonstrate this.

```
$.each(lines, function(n, elem) {

    var last = elem[elem.length -1];

    if (last === "}") {
        level--;
    }

    var tab = "    ".repeat(level);

    lines[n] = tab + elem + "\n";

    if (last === "{") {
        level++;
    }
 });

 lines = lines.join('');

 $('.beautified').text(lines);
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NdezxM